# When making requests with parse an exception is thrown with the message "This header must be modified with the appropiate property."

Tags: parse-platform, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm working on a project with a parse backend. I have run into an issue where I always get an exception when making requests on Android.

> [mono] System.ArgumentException: This header must be modified with the appropiate property.
>   [mono]   at System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.CheckRestrictedHeader (System.String headerName) [0x00000] in :0 
>   [mono]   at System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.Set (System.String name, System.String value) [0x00000] in :0 
>   [mono]   at System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.Set (HttpRequestHeader header, System.String value) [0x00000] in :0 
>   [mono]   at System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.set_Item (HttpRequestHeader header, System.String value) [0x00000] in :0 
>   [mono]   at Parse.PlatformHooks+d__19.MoveNext () [0x00000] in :0

The strange thing is, this is only an issue on Xamarin.Android. My code works fine on Xamarin.iOs and Windows Phone 8.

What could be causing the invalid header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is already fixed and will be published soon. I had the same problem and for now I use the version 1.3.2
Link to the bug: 
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1578599005710317/